# Can't set group ID bit on directory

Tags: permissions, setgid

I have created a directory called `newDir` and changed the group it belongs to with `mkdir newDir && chgrp test-group newDir`.

I was user `me` when I did this.

Calling `stat newDir` produces expected output:

```
  File: newDir
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 10756102    Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1001/      me)   Gid: ( 1003/test-group)
Access: 2018-01-27 17:03:07.514864274 +0100
Modify: 2018-01-27 17:03:07.514864274 +0100
Change: 2018-01-27 17:05:08.317543163 +0100
 Birth: -
```

Later, logged in as user `otherUser`, I tried to set the group ID (setgid) permission bit on the directory using `chmod g+s newDir`.

Disappointingly, I see with `stat` that the permissions haven't changed. I got no error on stderr, though, and the result of the `chmod` command is 0, as shown by `echo $?`.

Why did `chmod g+s newDir` have no effect?

I'm on Arch Linux 4.14.13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `chmod g+s newDir` didn't succeed when executed as user `otherUser`, was that `otherUser` wasn't part of group `test-group`, which is the group of `newDir`.

Switching to a user that is part of `test-group` and doing `chmod g+s newDir` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The add to Matthias' answer, if you wanted to do it numerically and absolutely, that'd be

```
chmod 2755 newDir
```

If you want to add yourself to the group you're targeting:

```
usermod -a -G otheruser test-group
newgrp
```

Sometimes newgrp doesn't seem to refresh groups, so you may need to relogin.

Weird that one has to be part of group they're trying to set the GUID bit for and that it fails without error, but that's how it is.